# Configuring Sharepoint in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, scripting, sharepoint-2010

Can you script SharePoint configuration (as in settings done in the "Configure your SharePoint farm" and "Reporting Services Configuration Manager") through .Net ?

Does anyone have any links that might help ?

Comment: You should take a look at Spencer Harbar's website. He's got all sorts of goodies on there: >[harbar.net][1] [1]:http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010mt4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to automate configuration of SharePoint 2010

1. Using PowerShell
2. Using SharePoint Object Model

I prefer first option because of shorter learning curve (compared to option 2) and yet have the power of .NET. There are plenty of resources available online. I would suggest you explore the cmdlets of PowerShell and see if it has everything available that you need. Also, you can create your own cmdlets in .NET (consuming SharePoint Object Model) so in theory, it is as powerful as option 2.